# My css are mixing up when enter to website from linkedin app (In Browser)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

How can i fix this issue: [Click Here](https://vimeo.com/566111008)

When i enter to site through linkedin app in iPhone i'm getting css issues,
But in android everything works fine.

someone know the solution for this problem?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have currently deployed a development build. You need to deploy a production build instead of a development one.

Please refer:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#build
- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#production
- https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment

The CSS issues you are getting are because [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) is not run on development builds, and as a result your CSS is missing vendor specific prefixes like `-webkit`, `-moz`, etc.

On Android (Chrome), the styles are working probably because you are not using any CSS property which is not supported in its standard form. While on iOS, the webview (or whatever Apple calls it) is powered by Safari, which may require `-webkit` prefix for the same properties.

Some references:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config#default-behavior
- https://www.caniuse.com/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

Comment: Thanks for the comments, this link is in production: https://cecilia-frontend.vercel.app/ and i still getting the same issue. you have any idea why? or which css properties I need to insert to disabled this behavior?

Comment: There are plenty of things that you can do to debug your app. This article covers most of the options: https://css-tricks.com/debugging-ios-safari/. On the styles section you will see the properties being either grayed out or struckthrough. You need to fix those (or provide fallback for those). Also you should think of upgrading the React version of the site. Although it's unrelated, but it is possible you  might be using older Next.js version itself. And please check that if you are using a custom postcss config you have configured autoprefixer there.